# Replacing HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Can you explain why this is not working? I am getting a syntax error!

HTML :

```
<a id="Navy">Navy</a>
<div id="replace1">
   <a href="Photos of T shirts/SITBRBV1_big.png"  id="zoom01" class="cloud-zoom">
     <img id="maneP" src="Photos of T shirts/SITBRBV1.png" alt="" align="top"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function () {
    $('#Navy').click(function () {
        $('#replace1').html(
            '<a href="Photos of T shirts/SITBRNV1_big.png" id="zoom01" class="maneA cloud-zoom" rel="adjustX:20, adjustY:-3, tint:'#FFFFFF ', softFocus:1, smoothMove:5, tintOpacity:0.8"><img id="maneP" src="Photos of T shirts/SITBRNV1.png" alt="" align="top"/></a>'
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of replacewith , did you try $('#replace1').html();

Comment: There a missing set of }); at the end there. Plus if I were you I'd whack a ; after the replace statement.

Comment: I think you have a little issue with your quotes starting at: tint:'#FFFFFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes:

```
tint:'#FFFFFF '
```

to

```
tint:#FFFFFF
```

Answer (score 1):

`.empty()` the element and `.append()` new data.

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
         $('#Navy').click(function(){
             $('#replace1').empty().append('<a href="Photos of T shirts/SITBRNV1_big.png" id="zoom01" class="maneA cloud-zoom" rel="adjustX:20, adjustY:-3, tint:\'#FFFFFF \', softFocus:1, smoothMove:5, tintOpacity:0.8"><img id="maneP" src="Photos of T shirts/SITBRNV1.png" alt="" align="top"/></a>');
             location.reload(); // reload page
         });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a way to reload the page with the replaced HTML?

Comment: Why would you need a reload ?!! anyway you may do this by one of these 3 methods: ... window.location.reload() .... history.go(0) ... window.location.href=window.location.href

Comment: simple `location.reload()`

Comment: @AshrafBashir Because the code is connected to some 'hover enlarge photo' jQuery app. And it doesn't seem to work if you just change the code?

Comment: you can escape str : `\'`

Comment: @M1K1O where do you put location.reload() ?

Comment: Where you want to reload page.

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing set of }); 
I see that you fixed it by editing the question !!

Here's a full running sample:

HTML:

```
<a id="Navy">Navy -- Click Me </a>

<div id="replace1">
    <a href="Photos of T shirts/SITBRBV1_big.png" id="zoom01" class="cloud-zoom"><img id="maneP" src="http://www.v3.co.uk/IMG/106/255106/google-logo--370x229.jpg?1365426001" alt="" align="top"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
     $('#Navy').click(
         function(){
             $('#replace1').replaceWith('<a href="Photos of T shirts/SITBRNV1_big.png" id="zoom02" class="cloud-zoom"><img id="maneP" src="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/images/casestudy/MicrosoftLogo.jpg" alt="" align="top"/> </a>')
         }
     );
});
```

Try it in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/xEPEd/